# Unity, keyboard layout in bionic and focal

Tags: 18.04, unity, 20.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm that person who does `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop` right after installing ubuntu.

Both in bionic and focal I'm experiencing the following erratic behavior:

- if I login into Unity after boot I'm unable to switch keyboard layouts with a keyboard shortcut (but I can do it with the mouse),
- if I login into Gnome first, logout and login into Unity, switching keyboard layouts with a keyboard works.

I tried searching around but I'm not able to tell what's wrong.

Currently I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, `unity` version 7.5.0+18.04.20190304-0ubuntu1.

More debugging info:

```
~ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
@as []
~ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options | hexdump -C
00000000  40 61 73 20 5b 5d 0a                              |@as [].|
00000007
```

Update: I've been initially using Super+space (which failed). Currently, as I played with settings, I've found out that CtrlL+ShiftL or CapsLock can switch layouts - that will work for me. (Interestingly, going back to Super+Space doesn't work)

Update 2: no, it's not working :(

Comment: Please define "a keyboard shortcut". Is it <Super>+Space, i.e. the desktop's default shortcut, or did you change it to something else, or did you set an alternative shortcut as an XKB option via e.g. Tweaks?

Comment: Yes, it's <Super>+Space.

Comment: Ok. I couldn't reproduce it on hirsute. <Super>+Space works for me to switch input source if I log in to a Unity session directly after boot. Nothing comes to mind which would explain why you see that issue on 18.04 and 20.04. Can you please edit your question and show us the output from this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: Thank you. I've added the output.

Comment: That output shows that there are no user specific settings which might cause the issue. I'm out of ideas. Well, possibly you could try to create an additional user for test purposes and find out if the issue is present for that user as well.